# live updates of google trends api python

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-trends

Hi I played with pytrends for few hours and wonder if there is a way to get live updates and not only historical value of specific keyword?

I want to train model that use the google trends but what can I do if I don't have live data.

Any websocket or something similar will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

According to [this support article](https://support.google.com/trends/answer/4365533?hl=en), Google Trends includes the following data:

- Historial non-real-time data (2004–present; +36 hours before prior to search)
- Real-time data ([last 7 days](https://medium.com/google-news-lab/what-is-google-trends-data-and-what-does-it-mean-b48f07342ee8))